# Multiplying a log-concave function to a Gaussian probability density reduces its variance

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian, moments

Let $X$ be a random Gaussian vector with probability density $p_X(x)$. Let $Y$ be the random variable with density proportional to $p_X(x)e^{-g(x)}$ for some convex function $g$. Does it hold that
$$
Cov(X)-Cov(Y)
$$
is always a (semi-)definite matrix?

Is the inverse also true? That is, suppose that

- $X$ is a random vector with probability measure $P$,
- For all convex functions $g$ that $Ee^{-g(X)}=1$, the random vector $Y$ with probability measure $e^{-g(x)}\mathrm dP(x)$ has that $Cov(X)-Cov(Y)$ is (semi-)definite,

then $X$ is Gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is positive. You may reduce to the case where $Cov(X)$ is the identity matrix, and then use a famous result by Caffarelli: under your hypothesis, there is contraction $T$ such that $p_Y$ is obtained as the image measure of the standard Gaussian measure under $T$. Since contractions decrease covariance, the result follows.

If you allow for discrete distributions, a uniform distribution on a $2$-element set is a counterexample for the second question.